# Checking an int within range

Tags: java, if-statement, comparison, integer

Is there an elegant way in java to check if an int is equal to, or 1 larger/smaller than a value.

For example, if I check `x` to be around `5`. I want to return true on `4, 5 and 6`, because 4 and 6 are just one away from 5.

Is there a build in function to do this? Or am I better off writing it like this?

```
int i = 5;
int j = 5;
if(i == j || i == j-1 || i == j+1)
{
    //pass
}
//or
if(i >= j-1 && i <= j+1)
{
    //also works
}
```

Of course the above code is ugly and hard to read. So is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find the absolute difference between them with `Math.abs`

```
private boolean close(int i, int j, int closeness){
    return Math.abs(i-j) <= closeness; 
}
```

Based on @GregS comment about overflowing if you give `Math.abs` a difference that will not fit into an integer you will get an overflow value

```
Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE - Integer.MAX_VALUE) //gives 1
```

By casting one of the arguments to a long `Math.abs` will return a long meaning that the difference will be returned correctly

```
Math.abs((long) Integer.MIN_VALUE - Integer.MAX_VALUE) //gives 4294967295
```

So with this in mind the method will now look like:

```
private boolean close(int i, int j, long closeness){
    return Math.abs((long)i-j) <= closeness; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, I'll go with this one since it's the most readable solution. Helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

use `Math.abs(x-5) <= 1` as a simple test. However, elegant is in the eye of the beholder. Strive for clarity instead.

Note than in general, for something like Glitch's fine answer or even this, there are overflow conditions that must be analyzed and understood. For correctness over all possible ints you should cast the arguments to long and perform the comparison using longs.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, it works but I'll go with @Glitch's answer since it's more readable in the end. Thanks!

Comment: @Pieter888: your welcome. I will add a few caveats to my answer as I am a nitpicker :)